# Getting Sid from PeoplePicker

Tags: people-picker

I'm trying to get Sid values for picker entities.. PickerEntity does not have any Sid field..

I can check every PickerEntity find the type (i.e. user, group) then load SPUser etc to get the Sid.

Is there an cleaner way to get Sid's from PickerEntities ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
ServerContext ctx = ServerContext.GetContext("Litware SSP");
UserProfileManager mgr = new UserProfileManager(ctx);

PickerEntity selectedEntity = (PickerEntity)PeopleEditor1.ResolvedEntities[0];
UserProfile profile = mgr.GetUserProfile(selectedEntity.Key);

string selectedSid = profile["SID"].Value.ToString();
```

Read the post [PeopleEditor Control](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/peopleeditor-control/) for details.

Comment: thanks,but that functionality requires MOSS, I have to be compatible with WSS 3..

Answer (score 0):

The GetUserInfo operation of the UserGroup.asmx web service contains the SID that can be parsed out if you can utilize that.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<GetUserInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"><User IsDomainGroup="False" IsSiteAdmin="False" Notes="" Email="myemail@mydomain.com" LoginName="domain\alexandere" Name="Pirate, Eric" Sid="S-1-5-21-2072177302-1958620249-3085007271-234531" ID="1"/>
</GetUserInfo>
</xml>
```

Meaning that after a user is selected from the people picker, you can use that value to call the web service to retrieve the SID.

Comment: I try not to use WebService since I'm already in sharepoint context.. do you know any other way ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'm not a C# developer.  I deal mainly with jQuery and DVWPs so I'm used to the web services route.